# IntelliJ IDEA forward-engineering with UML?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml

From IntelliJ IDEA Help System on UML:

> **Forward engineering**, which enables you to design and create a visual
>   model, and populate it with node elements, members and relationships.
>   IntelliJ IDEA automatically generates source code and keeps it
>   synchronized with the model.

...but it does not tell you how to do that. I know how to show the UML Diagram for existing classes (Right click on a class file from *Project* window, select *Diagrams* > *Show Diagram.*

What I want to do is the other way around: Create UML Class Diagrams, and generate method stubs from those diagrams.

Comment: Have you asked on the [Intellij site](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/ideacommunity)?  My experience is that they are _very_ responsive - and this is the kind of question they should hear to make it better, or better documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this, i think you have to click show diagram in a certain source folder or package and then right click in the diagram and you will have the option to create classes or interfaces. When right-clicking on a class there will also be an option to create methods and fields in this class.

So folow the show diagram, then right click and use the context menu to create classes/methods etc.